# How to decrease whitespace beneath header for just one page?

Tags: xetex, header-footer, margins

I have one particular page of my document that needs its body text to be closer to the header than all other pages. Is there a way to easily adjust the header padding for a single page? Perhaps by temporarily activating a new `fancypagestyle`, or usign `afterpage`? Or something similar? I've tried to cook something up but every time I get near success I screw something up downstream int the document.

Also, `vskip` will not work, I've tried this in many different configurations, as I suppose a header is not a `float` in the same way that figures and tables are? Btw, I'm using `fancyhdr` for headers and footers.

Apologies for lacking a minimal working example, I can't reproduce the issue to save my life and it would not be helpful to paste in my entire document (it's quite large)

Comment: I understand that you don’t want to post the whole document. This is actually not needed. But what *is* needed in order to help you, is to know your document setup. Can’t you paste at leat this with a bit of filler text maybe?

Comment: `\vspace*{-20pt}` will work if you put it in the right place, you say `\vspace` will not work but since you gave no indication of what you did hard to say if it did not work for you because you omitted the `*` or because you put it in the wrong place.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what does the `*` do?

Comment: `\vspace*` is like `\vspace` but prevents the space being discarded at top of page, just as `\hspace*` prevents horizontal space being dropped at start of a line

Comment: by the way it's more common to squeeze over-large content on to a page by extending the bottom rather than the top, latex has a standard `\enlargethispage` command for that case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, `vspace*` worked. It's not that I have over-large content, it's that a large whitespace was appearing just beneath the header of one of my pages and I could not identify the cause (I _was_ squeezing figures onto the page before it, but playing around with them only made for more confusion). In either case, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\vspace*` which is like `\vspace` but prevents the space being discarded at top of page, just as `\hspace*` prevents horizontal space being dropped at start of a line.